# Выбрать текст с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте. Я совершенно нуб в кодинге, пишу себе небольшое дополнение для Хрома которое облегчит мою удаленную работу.
У меня есть часть кода:

```
<div class="class"><div class="class2"><div>Marcos, M, 18</div><b>useremail@gmail.com</b></div></div>
```

Мне необходимо вытащить из него текст ***Marcos, M, 18***

Пробую так:

```
var contentAsText = contentToSearch.toString();
var data = contentAsText.match(/([a-zA-Z],+\s\[A-Z]/,+\s\,[0-9]+)/gi);
alert(data);
```

не выходит, спасибо заранее

Comment: `contentAsText.match(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/i)[1]`

Comment: как все просто оказалось) спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```js
contentAsText.match(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/i)[1]
```

Если есть такой текст, где совпадение может отсутствовать, нужно сначала проверить, есть ли совпадение:

```js
data = '';
var match = contentAsText.match(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/i)
if (match) {
  data = match[1]
}
```

Если текст между `div` может содержать переносы строк, замените регулярное выражение на

```js
/<div>([\w\W]*?)<\/div>/i
```